# How can I join these two select queries into one query?

Tags: oracle

this is my first time posting, so I am sure I will get a number of things wrong. Do not hesitate to correct me and I will do everything I can to clarify.

In Oracle SQL Developer, I am trying to take two separate SELECT statements and combine them to get one row of results. Unfortunately, because this is sensitive data, I am unable to give any results from the statements individually, but instead, just the SQL statements themselves. I suspect I should be able to join these two on the field "emplid" but just cannot get there. Any help is greatly appreciated! Here is the code below, please mind the syntax :)

1st Select statement is giving me a list of people that were paid in 2017:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.COMPANY,
 C.EMPLID,
 C.SSN
FROM PS_PAY_CHECK C
WHERE TO_CHAR(C.CHECK_DT,'YYYY') = '2017'
AND C.COMPANY                   IN ('001','054','076')
ORDER BY C.COMPANY, C.EMPLID
```

And 2nd Select statement would be a list of the deductions taken for the employees that were identified in the first statement:

```
SELECT G.EMPLID, G.DEDCD,
  CASE
   WHEN DC.DED_CLASS IN ('A','B','T')
   THEN G.DED_ADDL_AMT
   ELSE 0
  END AS "EEAmt",
  CASE
   WHEN DC.DED_CLASS NOT IN ('A','B','T')
   THEN G.DED_ADDL_AMT
   ELSE 0
  END AS "ERAmt",
  DC.DED_CLASS,
  G.DED_ADDL_AMT,
  G.GOAL_AMT
FROM PS_GENL_DEDUCTION G,
 PS_DED_CLASS_VW DC
WHERE G.EFFDT =
 (SELECT MAX(G_ED.EFFDT)
 FROM PS_GENL_DEDUCTION G_ED
 WHERE G.EMPLID  = G_ED.EMPLID
 AND G.COMPANY   = G_ED.COMPANY
 AND G.DEDCD     = G_ED.DEDCD
 AND G_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE
 )
AND ( G.DEDUCTION_END_DT IS NULL
OR G.DEDUCTION_END_DT     > SYSDATE)
AND ( G.GOAL_AMT          = 0.00
OR G.GOAL_AMT            <> G.GOAL_BAL)
AND G.DED_ADDL_AMT        > 0
AND DC.PLAN_TYPE          = '00'
AND DC.DEDCD              = G.DEDCD
AND DC.EFFDT              =
 (SELECT MAX(V1.EFFDT)
 FROM PS_DED_CLASS_VW V1
 WHERE V1.PLAN_TYPE = DC.PLAN_TYPE
 AND V1.DEDCD       = DC.DEDCD
 )
AND G.EMPLID = 'XXXXXX'
```

Ideally, what I'd like to do is put in a value in place of 'XXXXXX' and get one row of data with the two combined statements.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You have the two result sets from these queries. Lets call them "A" and "B". Imagine if they were their own tables called "TableA" and "TableB". How would you join the two of them? What fields are common between them? It's not at all clear by just looking at the sql.

Comment: Hi JNevill, the commonality between them is emplid. Sorry, I did not put that in the original question.

Comment: Your second result set does not have a field called `empid`. It only outputs `DEDCD, EEAMT, ERAMT, DED_CLASS, DED_ADDL_AMT, and GOAL_AMT`. You'll have to figure out how to get `empid` into that second query's result set/output in order to join the results.

Comment: Thanks JNevill, I updated the second select statement to include g.emplid along with g.dedcd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, we stick each SELECT statement into a subquery and give that subquery an alias to refer to in the main queries select statement:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT C.COMPANY,
         C.EMPLID,
         C.SSN
        FROM PS_PAY_CHECK C
        WHERE TO_CHAR(C.CHECK_DT,'YYYY') = '2017'
        AND C.COMPANY                   IN ('001','054','076')
        ORDER BY C.COMPANY, C.EMPLID
    ) t1
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT G.EMPLID, G.DEDCD,
          CASE
           WHEN DC.DED_CLASS IN ('A','B','T')
           THEN G.DED_ADDL_AMT
           ELSE 0
          END AS "EEAmt",
          CASE
           WHEN DC.DED_CLASS NOT IN ('A','B','T')
           THEN G.DED_ADDL_AMT
           ELSE 0
          END AS "ERAmt",
          DC.DED_CLASS,
          G.DED_ADDL_AMT,
          G.GOAL_AMT
        FROM PS_GENL_DEDUCTION G,
         PS_DED_CLASS_VW DC
        WHERE G.EFFDT =
         (SELECT MAX(G_ED.EFFDT)
         FROM PS_GENL_DEDUCTION G_ED
         WHERE G.EMPLID  = G_ED.EMPLID
         AND G.COMPANY   = G_ED.COMPANY
         AND G.DEDCD     = G_ED.DEDCD
         AND G_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE
         )
        AND ( G.DEDUCTION_END_DT IS NULL
        OR G.DEDUCTION_END_DT     > SYSDATE)
        AND ( G.GOAL_AMT          = 0.00
        OR G.GOAL_AMT            <> G.GOAL_BAL)
        AND G.DED_ADDL_AMT        > 0
        AND DC.PLAN_TYPE          = '00'
        AND DC.DEDCD              = G.DEDCD
        AND DC.EFFDT              =
         (SELECT MAX(V1.EFFDT)
         FROM PS_DED_CLASS_VW V1
         WHERE V1.PLAN_TYPE = DC.PLAN_TYPE
         AND V1.DEDCD       = DC.DEDCD
         )
        AND G.EMPLID = 'XXXXXX'
    ) t2 ON
    t1.empid = t2.empid
```

We just treat each derived table/subquery as it's own table and join them on empid. You can tweak the SELECT statement at the top as needed.

This is similar to creating a view for both sql statements and then referencing the views in a third sql statement.

An alternative way of doing this is to use CTE (Common Table Expressions) to house the separate sql. There's no performance advantage here, but you might find it easier to read.

```
WITH t1 as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT C.COMPANY,
     C.EMPLID,
     C.SSN
    FROM PS_PAY_CHECK C
    WHERE TO_CHAR(C.CHECK_DT,'YYYY') = '2017'
    AND C.COMPANY                   IN ('001','054','076')
    ORDER BY C.COMPANY, C.EMPLID
),
t2 AS
(
    SELECT G.EMPLID, G.DEDCD,
      CASE
       WHEN DC.DED_CLASS IN ('A','B','T')
       THEN G.DED_ADDL_AMT
       ELSE 0
      END AS "EEAmt",
      CASE
       WHEN DC.DED_CLASS NOT IN ('A','B','T')
       THEN G.DED_ADDL_AMT
       ELSE 0
      END AS "ERAmt",
      DC.DED_CLASS,
      G.DED_ADDL_AMT,
      G.GOAL_AMT
    FROM PS_GENL_DEDUCTION G,
     PS_DED_CLASS_VW DC
    WHERE G.EFFDT =
     (SELECT MAX(G_ED.EFFDT)
     FROM PS_GENL_DEDUCTION G_ED
     WHERE G.EMPLID  = G_ED.EMPLID
     AND G.COMPANY   = G_ED.COMPANY
     AND G.DEDCD     = G_ED.DEDCD
     AND G_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE
     )
    AND ( G.DEDUCTION_END_DT IS NULL
    OR G.DEDUCTION_END_DT     > SYSDATE)
    AND ( G.GOAL_AMT          = 0.00
    OR G.GOAL_AMT            <> G.GOAL_BAL)
    AND G.DED_ADDL_AMT        > 0
    AND DC.PLAN_TYPE          = '00'
    AND DC.DEDCD              = G.DEDCD
    AND DC.EFFDT              =
     (SELECT MAX(V1.EFFDT)
     FROM PS_DED_CLASS_VW V1
     WHERE V1.PLAN_TYPE = DC.PLAN_TYPE
     AND V1.DEDCD       = DC.DEDCD
     )
    AND G.EMPLID = 'XXXXXX'
)

SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON
    t1.empid = t2.empid
```

Comment: This is great. I tried something similar but I was getting hung up on the fact that the emplid fields were c.emplid in the first statement, and g.emplid in the second. Thank you J, you made that seem too easy.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do something like

```
select blah, blah.. (your second query )
AND G.EMPLID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT C.COMPANY,
                  C.EMPLID,
                  C.SSN
                  FROM PS_PAY_CHECK C
                  WHERE TO_CHAR(C.CHECK_DT,'YYYY') = '2017'
                  AND C.COMPANY                   IN ('001','054','076')
                 )
```

So basically I have used your first query in you second query. I removed the DISTINCT, as its not needed.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Bob - I tried this also but probably messed up the syntax as I received some errors. JNevill was able to resolve for me, but thank you for your input and help!

Comment: No worries.I like JNevill's approach of use the CTE, so thats good :)